# How can I add an nft to a collection TypeScript

Tags: nft, metaplex-js, collection

Is there a way I can add an NFT to an already existing collection?

I am the authority for this collection and was wondering whether this is possible in TypeScript without the use of metaplex candy machine.

Answer (score 1):

the title of your question and the content of it speak about 2 different cases.

To add an nft to an existing collection, you can just mint an nft, and in the metadata you put this collection mint address, and then once minted, there is a metaplex instruction to verify the collection.

you don't need a candy machine to do that, you can build your own transaction with your instructions inside